# How get Year only in the api json

Tags: asp.net, .net-core

Here I created an API in which I getting the average value and year in the from the table column **createdAt**.

```
public async Task<ICollection<SchoolSystemOverallAveragePerYearVm>> GetSchoolSystemOverallAveragePerYear(Guid schoolSystemId)
{
    var schoolsystemYearAvg = _GpsContext.SchoolSystem.Where(s => s.Id == schoolSystemId);
    var tem = _GpsContext.AssignmentStudents
        .Include(a => a.Assignment)
        .ThenInclude(s => s.SchoolSystems)
        .GroupBy(g => // Group by your Key-Values Grade and Course (You could take names instead of ids. Just for simplification)
            new {
                Year = g.CreatedAt,// CreateAt is the column name in the table datetime type.
            })
        .Select(g => // Select the result into an anonymous type
            new SchoolSystemOverallAveragePerYearVm
            {
                Year = g.Key.Year.ToString(),
                AverageObtainedMarks = g.Average(a => a.ObtainedMarks) // and an average ObtainedMarks from objects matching the key
            });

    List<SchoolSystems> schoolSystems = await schoolsystemYearAvg.ToListAsync();

    var averageYearVms = await tem.ToListAsync();
    return averageYearVms;
}
```

Now the JSON result is like this:

```
 [
  {
    "averageObtainedMarks": 90,
    "year": "04/04/2019 00:00:00"
  },
  {
    "averageObtainedMarks": 30,
    "year": "04/04/2020 00:00:00"
  }
]
```

I want to get **Year** only as year like formate **2020**

Comment: How about grouping by year instead of date: `.GroupBy(g => new { Year = g.CreatedAt.Year })` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the code and it is working :

```
.GroupBy(g => 
    new
    {
        Year = g.CreatedAt.Value.Year,// CreateAt is type column name in the table.
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

How about grouping by year instead of date:

```
public async Task<ICollection<SchoolSystemOverallAveragePerYearVm>> GetSchoolSystemOverallAveragePerYear(Guid schoolSystemId)
{
    var tem = _GpsContext.AssignmentStudents
        .Include(a => a.Assignment)
        .ThenInclude(s => s.SchoolSystems)
        // Group by year - CreatedAt is nullable DateTime
        .GroupBy(g => g.CreatedAt?.Year)
        .Select(g => new SchoolSystemOverallAveragePerYearVm
            {
                Year = g.Key.ToString(),
                AverageObtainedMarks = g.Average(a => a.ObtainedMarks) // and an average ObtainedMarks from objects matching the key
            });

    var averageYearVms = await tem.ToListAsync();
    return averageYearVms;
}
```

I've removed the unused code and grouped on a single value rather than an anonymous type.

This would get you the following JSON:

```
[
  {
    "averageObtainedMarks": 90,
    "year": "2019"
  },
  {
    "averageObtainedMarks": 30,
    "year": "2020"
  }
]
```

Comment: It is showing following error: Error CS1061 'DateTime?' does not contain a definition for 'Year' and no accessible extension method 'Year' accepting a first argument of type 'DateTime?' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @VipinJha Why would CreatedAt be nullable? Anyway, change `g.CreatedAt.Year` to `g.CreatedAt?.Year` - will amend answer accordingly.